# Strapi instalation has error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432

Tags: postgresql, strapi

I just install Strapi but with PostgreQL DB (not using -- quickstart which means SQLite)

`1. yarn create strap'-app name-of-my-project,`

`2. submit all QA=default step-by-step (database=strapi, port=default, login/password nothing fancy, and last without SSL connection)`

And the finall result is not so descriptive. Only server error with connecting, which I don't know

`Connection test failed: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5433`

## Problem solved!  (after 2 hours of trying instalation)

The answer is  => **You have to install PostgreSQL DB too on your computer**

Once its done, next, you can **run Strapi** by `yarn develop`

So the problem is solved. Other problem in meantime solved

`Server wasn't able to start properly. Error: The server does not support SSL connections. Try to install without SSL connection (last question in Strapi install process)

Comment: When you say that we **have to install PostgreSQL DB** locally, do you mean that we also have to create the database and its user ?

Comment: Yes, it is, you do

Comment: @sleepydrmike is there a tutorial or documentation on how to do that?

Comment: @conor909 I didn't do it his way finally, since usually you first create you project locally and then worry about deployment. Here is a very descriptive tutorial on how to deploy your local Strapi backend to a VPS: https://medium.com/@leodeo/deploying-strapi-version-4-on-linode-or-any-cloud-host-using-pm2-via-github-and-accessing-it-from-da87b52b7202. If you start with a blank server without anything installed, you'll need to install Postgres on your VPS (along with node and family), create a DB and then use env variables to use the postgres client in production and your local one in dev mode.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of downloading postgres you can apply docker and it works the same

Link: https://blog.dehlin.dev/docker-with-strapi-v4

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I know you resolved the issue but just posting this in case anybody needs specific instructions.

I followed this [tutorial](https://tute.io/install-configure-strapi-postgresql) and it's working for me now.

Sidenote: Once I installed Postgres and ran the command `psql postgres` it prompted me to enter my password. Despite putting in the correct password it still gave me an error that it is the wrong password, so I ran `psql postgres postgres` and then entering my password resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and as Kris says above, you need to install postgresql, pgAdmin and create the database first to then can create your Strapi project linked to you database.

I followed this [youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=41_1CA0RRTs) (in spanish) to solve it very easy.

Also need to avoid enable SSL for your local project. If you need to change this option in the future you can make it in the strapi config/database.js file.

Good luck!